# Connecting Laptop to External Monitor with DisplayPort returns Power Saving Message

Tags: 16.04, external-monitor, displayport

I'm wanting to connect my laptop to a monitor using the DisplayPort, however when I do this I get a "Entering power saving" message, followed by a blank screen.

Monitor: DELL U2515H
Laptop: Asus Zenbook 305 (I'm also testing on a Dell laptop and have the same issue)
[HDMI to DP wire adaptor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B010SDZZ80/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Does this mean my laptop's graphics card isn't able to use the DisplayPort? If I connect the laptop to the monitor using HDMI it works fine, however I need to connect it through DP so I may daisy chain a 3rd screen.

How may I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

1. [Rankie Gold-Plated DP DisplayPort to HDMI/Display Port to HDMI Cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B010SDZZ80/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) you have mentioned is a *DP-to-HDMI* adapter. However in your case, you need an *HDMI-to-DP* adapter.

   HDMI-to-DP adapters are active converters, so they are more expensive than DP-to-HDMI adapters.
2. You can't chain HDMI to get dual even if you convert it to DP. (You can't promote it, it is limited at the level of your 1st HDMI connection)

   **A,C&D** are electrically compatible with **single-link DVI-D**.
   **B** is electrically compatible with **dual-link DVI-D**.

   So only type B, may have passive splitter same as dual-link DVI-D adapters to run two separate monitors.

   [image]
   [image]

   **References:** 
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI 
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface

Answer (score 2):

you need to get a micro hdmi to hdmi cable to connect that laptop to that monitor , you have the wrong interface and the wrong cable for multiple displays.

HDMI doesn't support display chaining , the best you can do with that laptop is a single display , to do that you will need a mini hdmi to hdmi cable , display port will not be an option with that laptop.

if you want multiple displays you could try adding a displaylink usb adapter, however even with the recently updated drivers these displays are very slow and typicaly slow down all the other displays on the system.

Comment: OP says they need to use DisplayPort for extraneous reasons.

Comment: that laptop only has mini hdmi out , you need displayport with MST support on the laptop to do chaining. maybe the op is confused because there are devices that take a display port in and allow multiple hdmi monitors.  that laptop will only ever support 1 display unless you use something like a displaylink usb adapter

Comment: Good point. I didn't think of that from your answer alone and I suspect that neither would OP. Could you please add the explanation to your answer? Ping me if you want an up-vote on the result. :-]

Comment: @DavidFoerster The answer here has been edited but you weren't pinged.